How to prove a significant difference from a treatment variable across multiple categories?
I would like to see if a certain approach has a statistically significant effect on CPU Usage. I have raw data for each approach across five different levels of computational complexity.  This graph shows the mean of the cpu usage per category and treatment. How can this be done?
Im not quite sure what statistical methods could be used for this. I recognize the means can be paired, but the raw data cannot be. I also read up on some chi-square methods, but none seem to fit.

If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on Cross Validated Stack Exchange, where statistical analysis is on-topic.

You may need something like a two-way ANOVA. See, for example: Two-way ANOVA in R - Stats and R
